# SQL Server Dim Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform this join operation on date dimension but getting the following error. Could someone please tell me how to fix this?

> The multi-part identifier "Tot_Lines.DateKey" could not be bound.

Code:

```
select distinct
    Tot_Lines.CrewType,
    Tot_Lines.DateKey,
    Tot_Lines.Measure,
    Tot_Lines.Value as Tot_Lines,
    RSV_Lines.Value as Rsv_Lines,
    RSV_Lines.Scenario,
    LA.Value AS Line_Avg,
    RSV_Lines.Value * 75 AS Reserve_Hrs
from 
    FactProjections Tot_Lines, FactProjections RSV_Lines, FactProjections LA
left join
    DimDate DD on DD.DateKey = Tot_Lines.DateKey
where 
    Tot_Lines.Measure = 'Lines Required' 
    and Tot_Lines.Scenario = 'Projected'
    and RSV_Lines.Measure = 'RSV Lines 1' 
    and RSV_Lines.Scenario = 'Projected'
    and LA.Measure = 'Line Average' 
    and LA.Scenario = 'Projected'
    and Tot_Lines.DateKey = RSV_Lines.DateKey 
    and Tot_Lines.CrewType = RSV_Lines.CrewType
    and LA.DateKey = Tot_Lines.DateKey 
    and LA.DateKey = RSV_Lines.DateKey
    and LA.CrewType = Tot_Lines.CrewType 
    and LA.CrewType= RSV_Lines.CrewType
```

Comment: Please include your query and some sample data.  Your current question is unanswerable.

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Does FactProjections not have a DateKey column?

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using old-syle joins, and shouldn't be. You even mixed an explicit join in there. Regardless, your error should be because there is not column `DateKey`  in the table `FactProjections`. If you wrote this with explicit joins, it would be more legible:

```
select distinct
    Tot_Lines.CrewType,
    Tot_Lines.DateKey,
    Tot_Lines.Measure,
    Tot_Lines.Value as Tot_Lines,
    RSV_Lines.Value as Rsv_Lines,
    RSV_Lines.Scenario,
    LA.Value AS Line_Avg,
    RSV_Lines.Value * 75 AS Reserve_Hrs
from 
    FactProjections Tot_Lines
    inner join FactProjections RSV_Lines on 
        Tot_Lines.DateKey = RSV_Lines.DateKey 
        and Tot_Lines.CrewType = RSV_Lines.CrewType
        and RSV_Lines.Measure = 'RSV Lines 1' 
        and RSV_Lines.Scenario = 'Projected'
    inner join FactProjections LA on 
        LA.DateKey = Tot_Lines.DateKey 
        and LA.DateKey = RSV_Lines.DateKey          --this doesn't seem right
        and LA.CrewType = Tot_Lines.CrewType 
        and LA.CrewType= RSV_Lines.CrewType         --again, seems redundant 
        and LA.Measure = 'Line Average' 
        and LA.Scenario = 'Projected'
   left join DimDate DD on 
        DD.DateKey = Tot_Lines.DateKey
where 
    Tot_Lines.Measure = 'Lines Required' 
    and Tot_Lines.Scenario = 'Projected'
```

Comment: thanks for your response. DateKey exists in the table factprojections

Comment: @Sandy567 Can you update your question with the table/view definition of the FactProjections object?